# An error occurred while implementing the MADDPG algorithm using Python

Tags: pytorch

An error occurred while implementing the MADDPG algorithm using Python: "RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation".May I ask how to resolve this error？

May I ask how to resolve this error？